# Convert UTC to EST and save in EST format in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails application uses `UTC` format. However, I need to store the `created_at` in `EST` format just for one model.

How can this be achieved ?

If saved in UTC - I need to select records created on a particular date.
`Input - EST format date`
How can I convert the `created_at` datetime to `date` in `EST` and compare with the input date in `Where` clause?

Comment: Save yourself a ton of pain and only store UTC timestamps in your database. Convert them for display. That way when someone inevitably says they want to see the time in Pacific or Central you can write some code that shows it correctly for them as well.

Comment: @Cfreak If i save in UTC, how do i convert and query the records ? I need to select the records created on a particular day . The input is given in EST (just date). I need to get the date(created_at) converted from UTC to EST and then check in where clause

Comment: Convert the input from EST to UTC and then query your model.

Comment: use Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day and Time.now.utc.end_of_day in your query